# Google Apps Script - Exporting events from Google Sheets to Google Calendar - how can I stop it from removing my spreadsheet formulas?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I've been trying to create a code that takes info from a Google Spreadsheet, and creates Google Calendar events. I'm new to this, so bear with my lack of in-depth coding knowledge!

I initially used this post to create a code:
[Create Google Calendar Events from Spreadsheet but prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788897/create-google-calendar-events-from-spreadsheet-but-prevent-duplicates)

I then worked out that it was timing out due to the number of rows on the spreadsheet, and wasn't creating eventIDs to avoid the duplicates. I got an answer here to work that out!
[Google Script that creates Google Calendar events from a Google Spreadsheet - "Exceeded maximum execution time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806524/google-script-that-creates-google-calendar-events-from-a-google-spreadsheet-e/25818035?noredirect=1#comment40586082_25818035)

And now I've realised that it's over-writing the formulas, I have in the spreadsheet, auto-completing into each row, as follows:

```
Row 12 - =if(E4="","",E4+1) // Row 13 - =if(C4="","",C4+1) // Row 18 - =if(B4="","","WHC - "&B4) // Row 19 - =if(B4="","","Docs - "&B4)
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can stop it doing this?

```
/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, containing a single menu item
 * for invoking the exportEvents() function.
 * The onOpen() function, when defined, is automatically invoked whenever the
 * spreadsheet is opened.
 * For more information on using the Spreadsheet API, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Export WHCs",
    functionName : "exportWHCs"
  },
                {
    name : "Export Docs",
    functionName : "exportDocs"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Calendar Actions", entries);
};

/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportWHCs() {
  // check if the script runs for the first time or not,
  // if so, create the trigger and PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() the script will use
  // a start index and a total counter for processed items
  // else continue the task
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':0});
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportWHCs').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
  // initialize all variables when we start a new task, "notFinished" is the main loop condition
  var itemsProcessed = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('itemsprocessed'));
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 4;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "flightcentre.com.au_pma5g2rd5cft4lird345j7pke8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[12]);  // First column
    var title = row[18];           // Second column
    var tstart = new Date(row[15]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[16]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var id = row[17];              // Sixth column == eventId
    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
    }
    if (!event) {
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"));
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop).addEmailReminder(5).getId();
      row[17] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
    }
    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 240000){ // if > 4 minutes
      var processed = i+1;// save usefull variable
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':processed});
      range.setValues(data);
      MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'progress sheet to cal','item processed : '+processed);
      return;
    }    
    debugger;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}



/**
 * Export events from spreadsheet to calendar
 */
function exportDocs() {
  // check if the script runs for the first time or not,
  // if so, create the trigger and PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() the script will use
  // a start index and a total counter for processed items
  // else continue the task
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ 
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':0});
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportDocs').timeBased().everyMinutes(5).create();
  }
  // initialize all variables when we start a new task, "notFinished" is the main loop condition
  var itemsProcessed = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('itemsprocessed'));
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRows = 4;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var calId = "flightcentre.com.au_pma5g2rd5cft4lird345j7pke8@group.calendar.google.com";
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  for (i in data) {
    if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date(row[13]);  // First column
    var title = row[19];           // Second column
    var tstart = new Date(row[15]);
    tstart.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstart.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstart.setYear(date.getYear());
    var tstop = new Date(row[16]);
    tstop.setDate(date.getDate());
    tstop.setMonth(date.getMonth());
    tstop.setYear(date.getYear());
    var id = row[20];              // Sixth column == eventId
    // Check if event already exists, update it if it does
    try {
      var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
    }
    catch (e) {
      // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
    }
    if (!event) {
      //cal.createEvent(title, new Date("March 3, 2010 08:00:00"), new Date("March 3, 2010 09:00:00"));
      var newEvent = cal.createEvent(title, tstart, tstop).addEmailReminder(5).getId();
      row[20] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
    }
    else {
      event.setTitle(title);
    }
    if(new Date().getTime()-startTime > 240000){ // if > 4 minutes
      var processed = i+1;// save usefull variable
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties({'itemsprocessed':processed});
      range.setValues(data);
      MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'progress sheet to cal','item processed : '+processed);
      return;
    }    
    debugger;
  }
  // Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ways to solve that problem.

First possibility : update your sheet with array data **only** on columns that have **no formulas**, proceeding as [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770080/how-to-set-values-for-all-columns-except-one/25770132#25770132) but in your case (with multiple columns to skip) it will rapidly become tricky

Second possibility : (the one I would personally choose because I 'm not a "formula fan") is to do what your formulas do in the script itself, ie translate the formulas into array level operations.

following your example `=if(E4="","",E4+1)` would become something like `data[n][4]=data[n][4]==''?'':data[n+1][4];` if I understood the logic (but I'm not so sure...).

---

### EDIT

There is actually a **third solution that is even simpler** (go figure why I didn't think about it in the first place...) You could save the ranges that have formulas, for example if col M has formulas you want to keep use :

`var formulM = sheet.getRange('G1:G').getFormulas();`

and then, at the end of the function (after the global `setValues()`) rewrite the formulas using :

```
sheet.getRange('G1:G').setFormulas(formulM);
```

to restore all the previous formulas... as simple as that, repeat for every column where you need to keep the formulas.